# append data based on what is checked or empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to append data into a table and I have to switches.
Each switch appends different text when It is checked.

When I check both they append right beside each other with a space but theres nothing to separate them so I added a "," into the append to separate them nicely.

The only problem is that if only one of them is checked it adds there text and with a comma beside it and no text further so it looks a bit odd.

here is the JS append code:

```
function addRow() {
    var item_text = $('#item-input').val();
    var item_color = $('#color-input').val();
    var size_text = $('#sizes-item').val();
    var any_color = $('#any-color').is(':checked') ? 'Any Color' : '';
    var any_size = $('#any-size').is(':checked') ? 'Any Size' : '';
    $('#items-table').append('<tr>'
        +'<td>'+item_text+', '+item_color+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+size_text+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+any_color+', '+any_size+'</td>'
        +'<td><button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">X</div></button><td>'
        +'</tr>');
}

$(function(){
  $('#add-item').click(function(){
    addRow();
    return false;
  });
```

I want to add something like if only one of them is checked to not add in a "," .

I also would like to add the same thing into the color-input. like if the color input is empty to not add a "," aswell.

I appreciate any help thank you <3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building a string in a linear fashion, you can build an array, filter out the empty items, and then join the remaining elements with commas.

```js
$('#add-item').on('click', function() {
  const itemData = [$('#item-input').val(), $('#color-input').val()]
    .filter(x => x != '')
    .join(', ');
    
    sizeData =  $('#sizes-item').val();

    checkboxData = [$('#any-color').is(':checked') ? 'Any Color' : '', $('#any-size').is(':checked') ? 'Any Size' : '']
    .filter(x => x != '')
    .join(', ');
  
  $('#items-table').append('<tr>'
        +'<td>'+itemData+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+sizeData+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+checkboxData+'</td>'
        +'<td><button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">X</div></button><td>'
        +'</tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="item-input">
<input id="color-input">
<input id="sizes-item">
<input id="any-color" type="checkbox">
<input id="any-size" type="checkbox">
<button id="add-item">Add Item</button>

<table id="items-table"></table>
```

Comment: what about the is checked stuff?

Comment: It'll be really similar, and you can use the ternary operator that you already have.Use the same type of statement with `[$('#any-color').is(':checked') ? 'Any Color' : '', $('#any-size').is(':checked') ? 'Any Size' : '']` as the array. I'll update the answer snippet to include this example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.filter` and `.join` would help. below is a working code

```js
$('#trigger').click(function() {

  var item_text = $('#item-input').val();
  var item_color = $('#color-input').val();
  var size_text = $('#sizes-item').val();
  var any_color = $('#any-color').is(':checked') ? 'Any Color' : '';
  var any_size = $('#any-size').is(':checked') ? 'Any Size' : '';

  var item = [any_color, item_color].filter(function(i) {
      return !!i;
    })
    .join(',');

  var sizeColor = [item_text, any_size].filter(function(i) {
      return !!i;
    })
    .join(',');
  $('#items-table').append('<tr>' +
    '<td>' + item + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + size_text + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + sizeColor + '</td>' +
    '<td><button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">X</div></button><td>' +
    '</tr>');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>


  <input type="text" id="item-input">
  <input type="text" id="color-input">
  <input type="text" id="sizes-item">
  <input type="checkbox" id="any-color">
  <input type="checkbox" id="any-size">


  <button id="trigger">Run</button>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
        <th>Four</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="items-table">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```